# About the nature of the electric current

Tags: electricity

I'm currently studying electricity on my own, and as I read in a metal electrons are moving across the metal freely (depending on the attraction of the nucleus). 
As we close the circuit, an electromagnetic waves spreads into the metal moving the electron from the minus pole to the plus pole.

Can someone explain to me why is there an electromagnetic wave created when we close the circuit and why it forces the electrons to move like this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: There's an *electric field* built up inside the conductor. I've never before heard that there should be an EM wave. What reference did you read that in?

Comment: Hi and thanks for this
Reference is from Mines de Douai course on electricity : "When the circuit is closed, an electromagnetic wave is moving at the speed of light leading to a movement of the free electrons across the circuit"

Comment: @ACuriousMind, well i could understand this in the sense that any EM wave is just an changing EM field

Comment: So I understand properly, the variation of the EM field leads to the creation of a EM wave, moving electrons around?

Comment: there are 2 types of EM wave probably meant here. 1. The act of closing the switch, indeed creates a  very rapid / sharp EM field (a spike) this coud be it. 2. Depending on the type of current (e.g alternating current) is also a changing EM field, in other words a kind of EM wave

Comment: Allright, thanks Nikos and CuriousMind for the answers :)